# Funcion ::WHERE en laravel no reconoce mi variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, querybuilder

Tengo dos formas de encontrar a mis empleados, una por el **No_emp(número de empleado)** y otra por el **TAG_emp(numero escaneado con la credencial)**. El formato del **TAG_emp** es un numero secuencial de 9 dígitos, con ese no tengo problemas. El detalle esta en el **No_emp** ya que está registrado en la BD con 7 dígitos (**ejemplo: 0023015**) y cuando quiero hacer mi búsqueda tengo que poner los ceros como viene en la BD, si ingreso el numero **23105** no encuentra al empleado, **tengo que colocar necesariamente 0023105** con los ceros al inicio.

Mi consulta es

```
$tag = substr($empleado->noEmpleado);
$datosEmpleado = Tbl_Empleado_SIA::WHERE('Status_Emp','=','A')->WHERE('No_Empleado','=',$tag)
        ->orWHERE('Status_Emp','=','A')->WHERE('No_TAG','=',$tag)
        ->get();
```

En esta consulta comparo la variable **$tag** que puede ser el numero de empleado tecleado o el numero de la credencial escaneado y que solo me traiga el registro con el **Status_Emp = A** que son los empleados activos. Porque en la empresa hay empleados que dejaron de trabajar pero despues vuelven a entrar y se les asigna el mismo numero de empleado con el que entraron la primera vez.

Intente colocarle los ceros al principio con la función `$tag = str_pad($empleado->noEmpleado,10,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);` pero la consulta no me trae nada. Porque lo guarda como texto y la funcion ::Where no me trae nada aunque el formato sea el correcto
Alguna idea?

Comment: En los dos `where` estás usando la misma variable. Podrías explicar eso? También estás usando dos where, por lo que tendrían que cumplirse ambas condiciones para que la consulta te devuelva algún registro. Ya que mencionas que son valores distintos (me refiero a lo que llamas "cantidad de digitos") lo más probable es que la consulta no devuelva ningún registro. Y por lo que mencionás de los ceros a la izquierda, probablemente estés trabajando con texto y no con números

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema lo tienes con el orWhere que has usado. Que no añade ningún parentesis y solo con cumplir la condición del estado = A ya es suficiente.

Suponiendo que la variable $tag tenga los números como quieres "0023015", esta consulta te irá mejor.

```
$tag = substr($empleado->noEmpleado);
$datosEmpleado = Tbl_Empleado_SIA::where('Status_Emp','=','A')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('No_Empleado','=',$tag)
                  ->orWhere('No_TAG','=',$tag);
        })
        ->get();
```

La clousre del segundo where es la que nos genera los paréntesis que necesitamos, sino pondrá un OR, y con solo cumplir el OR ya te entrarán los datos.

```
SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE status = 'A' AND (no_empleado = 1111 OR no_tag = 1111);
```

Todos los ->wheres encadenados como has puesto en tu pregunta genera una consulta de este estilo

```
SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE status = 'A' AND no_empleado = 1111 OR status = 'A' AND no_tag = 1111;
```

Con lo cual todos los empleados con el estado A son validos.

Puedes jugar con los where y con el metodo ->toSql() puedes ver que consulta te genera el eloquent. Es muy útil para entender como funciona.

```
$Tbl_Empleado_SIA::where(....)->where(....)->toSql();
```